# Python O(1) member data access possible?

Tags: python

In C++, for access to 'named' member data, we constantly do:

```
const unsigned int CHEESE_CAKE = 0;
const unsigned int CHOCOLATE_CAKE = 1;
...
const unsigned int CHERRY_PIE = 1050;
```

Then, when we want to access some specific resource matched to the string, we can simply do:

```
mResource[MyClass::CHEESE_CAKE]; // constant time O(1) access
```

I was attempting to do this in python in a similar fashion:

```
class MyClass:
    MY_CLASS_DATA1 = someData(1)
    MY_CLASS_DATA2 = someData(1)
```

But from my understanding, python's member functions are stored in `__dict__`, which is essentially a hash map giving O(logn) lookup time.

Is there a way achieve O(1) performance in python as in C++, or is this impossible due to python's dynamic nature?

Comment: You're comparing dictionary access with array access. Python has arrays too if that's what you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proper hash table implementations give amortized O(1) lookup time.  You're thinking of binary search trees when you mention O(log n) time.  Python name lookup is O(1).

Answer (score 3):

I think it's your lucky day: python dictionaries have an average complexity O(1) (see [TimeComplexity](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) on python wiki). You do not have to modify your existing code to improve performance.

On a slightly unrelated note, python objects differ quite a lot from C++ in memory usage, because of the dictionary.
Therefore, **if** you have memory issues and **lots** of objects, you could use [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots) to improve them; as usual with all optimizations, it is far better to delay them until you **see** their need, and only if you can measure they actually do something.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about member lookup performance, it's fast enough. Dictionary lookups can be safely considered O(1) in most circumstances.

If you want to throw dynamic lookup out the window, you can create a tuple of functions and have symbolic variables representing their index, I guess.

Edit:
Also, come on, Python vs. C++ in terms of speed? Be merciful, man! They are targeted at different things!

Comment: I think he's talking about complexity, not "speed".

Answer (score 0):

so what is n in log n? it is member count in dict and as long as it is not that big, which is often the case, this can be said to be O(1)